# Unhandled exception при обновлении версии Unity3d и работе с SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, unity3d

После того как Я обновил версию Unity с 5.3.2 до 5.3.4 случилось неприятное.

Я работал с SQLite посредством библиотек sqlite, Mono.Data.Sqlite, System.Data, и другие библиотеки из namespace System(Связанные с безопасностью).

База данных создавалась, таблицы создавались. То что было необходимо - работало.

Так вот, при обновлении появился такой Exception

> Internal compiler error at
>   Assets/Scripts/Data/DataBaseController.cs(56,17):: exception caught
>   while emitting MethodBuilder [DataBaseController::CreateTable]  The
>   class System.Runtime.InteropServices.CriticalHandle could not be
>   loaded, used in mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089  The class
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement could not be loaded, used in
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756

Новые библиотеки(из обновленной Unity) я подключил взамен старых.

Ошибка возникает в месте создания(вызовы конструктора )нового подключения.
При инициализации ошибки нет.

```
 SqliteConnection connection;
     connection = new SqliteConnection();
```